# what's the type of navigation for TabOneScreen({ navigation })?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using typescript, it pops error while I'm using react native navigation, so what exactly the type of nivation for the code `TabOneScreen({ navigation })`?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your navigator structure, but you can find more information in the React Navigation [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript#type-checking-screens).

They have this example for a simple stack navigator with a screen named `Profile`.

```js
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type ProfileScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'Profile'
>;

type Props = {
  navigation: ProfileScreenNavigationProp;
};
```